# In Ruby, how to tell two methods or two functions are the same?

Tags: ruby

For example, to check whether

```
CGI::parse == CGI.parse
```

(after doing `require "cgi"`), how can it be done?

Comment: `CGI::parse` is just another (rarely used) syntax for `CGI.parse`. There's no difference between the two.

Comment: To elaborate on @Stefan's astute comment, this is true of all class methods. `Klass.foo` is always the same as `Klass::foo`, for any `Klass` or `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`CGI.parse` is not valid code, since you are *calling* the method (without arguments, and the method requires one).

However, in ruby, (almost) **everything is an object** -- which includes methods! (A method is an instance of the class: `Method`.)

You can access the `CGI::parse` method via: `CGI.method(:parse)`.

Then, to check that two methods are equal, you can use [the `==` method on the `Method` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-3D-3D):

```
CGI.method(:parse) == CGI.method(:parse) #=> true
```

From the ruby documentation:

> Two method objects are equal if they are bound to the same object and refer to the same method definition and their owners are the same class or module.

Comment: if we do `CGI.method(:parse) == CGI.method(:parse)`, then it looks like it will be true. (just checking whether it equals itself). Can there be a more convincing statement to actually check `CGI::parse == CGI.parse`

Comment: `CGI::parse` is equivalent to `CGI.parse`. Also, technically, methods are NOT objects in Ruby, what `method(:name)` returns is merely a representation of the method, not the method itself.

Comment: If Ruby makes methods an object, is that possible or there are reasons they cannot be? JavaScript has the lost binding issue but one thing I like about JS is that all functions or methods are objects

Comment: @nopole Ruby methods aren't first class citizens. You have to call `method` to get a method object and it's mainly used for introspection (e.g. inspect a method's  parameters at runtime or find its owner). You typically don't pass instances of `Method` around in Ruby.